# How to avoid splitting data by index_level when writing to parquet with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark, parquet, pyarrow

Here is my simple code to write to parquet **using pandas**:

```
df.to_parquet(output_path)
```

This is what `df` is supposed to look like:

```
id          cosine_similarity                                   sub_id_list
111111111   [[0.99999994, 0.5283972, 0.9180976, 0.3284426,...   [1, 2, 3...]
222222222   [[1.0000004, 0.19264436, 0.40389958, 0.1159741...   [7, 8, 9...]
333333333   [[1.0, 0.7529702, 0.6990572, 0.5842277, 0.8533...   [12, 4, 2...]
444444444   [[0.9999998, 0.19949964, 0.3271717, 0.48022747...   [1, 2]
```

Some more details on the columns:

- `cosine_similarity`: N X N cosine similarity matrix
- `sub_id_list`: List of all of the N `sub_id` within a `id`

When I read the parquet files in my directory **in pyspark**, my cosine similarity matrix ends up splitting on a auto-generated index level:

```
+-----------------+--------------------+--------------------+---------+
|__index_level_0__|   cosine_similarity|              sub_id|       id|
+-----------------+--------------------+--------------------+---------+
|                0|[[0.9999996423721...|[6600381071465, 6...|222222222|
|                1|[[1.0000001192092...|[5961816244391, 6...|111111111|
|                2|[[1.0000001192092...|[6908383199422, 6...|333333333|
|                0|[[0.9999997615814...|[5961899770023, 5...|111111111|
|                1|[[1.0, 0.30099773...|[6794124132542, 6...|333333333|
|                0|             [[1.0]]|     [4637467902007]|444444444|
|                1|             [[1.0]]|     [5961974317223]|111111111|
|                2|[[1.0, 0.23061707...|[6807162486974, 6...|333333333|
|                0|[[1.0, 0.56126642...|[5961866641575, 5...|111111111|
|                1|[[1.0000002384185...|[6819049832638, 6...|333333333|
|                0|             [[1.0]]|     [4480999391337]|222222222|
```

With the way it's split, I won't be able to leverage my `cosine_sim` matrix.

Comment: `df.to_parquet` is pandas not pyspark

Comment: Sorry, I should be more clear. I'm writing to parquet using pandas and reading it in using pyspark.

Answer (score 1):

Using the following data as an example,

```
df.show()
+-----------------+-----------------+---------+---+
|__index_level_0__|cosine_similarity|   sub_id| id|
+-----------------+-----------------+---------+---+
|                0|   [[0.99, 0.98]]|[66, 615]|111|
|                1|    [[0.3, 0.18]]|[12, 513]|222|
|                2|   [[0.29, 0.38]]|[23, 122]|111|
|                0|   [[0.99, 0.31]]|[45, 935]|111|
|                1|         [[0.54]]|     [67]|111|
|                0|   [[0.53, 0.98]]|[78, 567]|222|
|                1|          [[1.0]]|     [89]|222|
|                2|   [[0.74, 0.72]]|[90, 445]|333|
|                0|   [[0.39, 0.32]]|[67, 334]|333|
|                1|   [[0.91, 0.85]]|[12, 223]|333|
|                0|          [[1.0]]|     [34]|333|
+-----------------+-----------------+---------+---+
```

You can use spark.sql functions to get the desired result like the following.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions

df = (df.groupBy("id")
       .agg(functions.flatten(
             functions.flatten(
              functions.collect_list("cosine_similarity"))).alias("cosine_similarity"), 
            functions.flatten(functions.collect_list("sub_id")).alias("sub_id")))

df.show()
+---+------------------------------------------+-------------------------------+
|id |cosine_similarity                         |sub_id                         |
+---+------------------------------------------+-------------------------------+
|333|[0.74, 0.72, 0.39, 0.32, 0.91, 0.85, 1.0] |[90, 445, 67, 334, 12, 223, 34]|
|222|[0.3, 0.18, 0.53, 0.98, 1.0]              |[12, 513, 78, 567, 89]         |
|111|[0.99, 0.98, 0.29, 0.38, 0.99, 0.31, 0.54]|[66, 615, 23, 122, 45, 935, 67]|
+---+------------------------------------------+-------------------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, I was really hoping to avoid writing parquets in this format rather than handle it after I ingest the parquet files.